# Sync thread by changing schedule priority

Tags: c, linux, multithreading

I found another way to sync thread from the source code of strongswan. It sync the thread by changing thread's schedule policy(`SCHED_FIFO`). Does it have any advantage over the `mutex` way?

[The code](https://github.com/strongswan/strongswan/blob/4.5.0/src/libstrongswan/utils/leak_detective.c):

```
int oldpolicy;
struct sched_param oldparams, params;
pthread_getschedparam(thread_id, &oldpolicy, &oldparams);
params.__sched_priority = sched_get_priority_max(SCHED_FIFO);
pthread_setschedparam(thread_id, SCHED_FIFO, &params);

...
critical section
...

pthread_setschedparam(thread_id, oldpolicy, &oldparams);
```

**PS:** strongswan use malloc hook to detect memory leak. To support multi-thread, it use this way to sync the threads.

**PPS:** It seems that they have modified the code. That piece of code from the version Strongswan 4.5.0.

Comment: No. It is an unusual way and may affect the whole system.

Comment: Not clear what you mean by "sync thread".

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin I think it means serialization.

Comment: The linked source does __not__ contain the listed code. Where does it come from?

Comment: @JanHudec my fault. it seems that they modify it. It comes from an old version strongswan 4.5.0.

Comment: @louxiu: I've updated the link. The branch/tag is part of the URL in github code view. Anyway, they don't say anything about synchronization there. Apparently they just wanted the code to run fast and not block another thread. It probably didn't have much effect since they deleted it (I don't know how to use pickaxe on github and don't want to fetch it just for that; if anybody can run pickaxe and find comments in the revisions that introduce and remove it, it might be interesting read).

Comment: @JanHudec So it is not for multi-threads support?

Comment: @JanHudec They use mutex before. https://github.com/strongswan/strongswan/commit/84b18d5fc7ff637eef76e79d2244b98a4a779675

Comment: @louxiu: Hm, they are definitely not up to Linus' standards of commit commenting. The comment does not explain anything at all...

Comment: @JanHudec yeah. They remove those code at this commit. Does not explain anything. https://github.com/strongswan/strongswan/commit/c9418d4fd3cda35a632c648a89f99bd6f8d1fe90

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**That does not synchronize anything!**

What this does is prevents the thread to be scheduled off the CPU while the critical section is running. Since we now have multiple CPUs and since different thread can run on another CPU, it does not exclude anything at all. And it does not even completely prevent preemption; the thread can still sleep if waiting on page fault or other IO.

The reason for it is to avoid starving other threads when something very important is being calculated without which the other threads can't continue. It does help that cause, but it's a very specialized case (search for "priority inversion").

Comment: It's broken in multiple ways.  I couldn't be bothered to list them all.

Answer (score 3):

It's broken if you have more than one core, unless you lock all threads that might conflict to the same core. And, even then, it's still broken if you block on I/O. (For example, a page fault.) Yuck.